# Specific usecase for java 8 stream and foreach

Tags: java-8

There is class A:

```
class A{

private String a;
private String b;
private String status;

/*
. getter & setter
*/

}
```

And I have a class B:

```
class B{
private List<List<A>> list;
}
```

I have to write a logic to iterate over the list of class A in class B to:

1. Make sure that the status of all the objects of A in the list is having a value of field status as "SUCCESS", if not then don't do step 2 and end the process
2. Get the value of field b when field a has a value of "test99" (This would be unique in the list)

Is it possible to do it using streams?

Comment: Should it stop as soon as one element has a status that is not `SUCCESS`?

Comment: @dan1st, yes it should stop

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with Java 8 Streams but I would use more than just `forEach()`:

```java
list.stream()//1
.flatMap(List::stream)//2
.filter(obj->!"SUCCESS".equals(obj.getStatus()))//3
.findAny()//4
.ifPresentOrElse(o->System.out.println(o+" is not successfull"),()->//5
    list.stream()//1
    .flatMap(List::stream)//2
    .filter(obj->"test99".equals(obj.getA()))//6
    .map(obj->obj.getB())//7
    .forEach(this::doSomething);//8
)
```

It does the following:

1. get a stream from `list`
2. convert each `List` in the stream to a `Stream` and make one stream out of all those streams containing all elements
3. get only the elements where `status` is not `SUCCESS`
4. get an Optional with an element where the status is not `SUCCESS`
5. Execute `System.out.println(o+" is not successfull")` if such an element exists (you can use `()->{}` if you don't want to do anythin in that case) or
6. get only the elements where a is `test99`
7. get the `b` value of those elements
8. run a method (in this case `doSomething()`) with the value of `b` as a parameter (you could use `collect()` if you want to e.g get those element in a `List`

Comment: But this will iterate the list twice correct?

Comment: Yes because you need to check if it contains an element that is not successfull